# Is it Possible to have a Form Submit Action based on different Views in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath

I have several different views in InfoPath 2010 and would like to apply rules on the "Form Submit" based on what the "Current" form view is.  I don't see anything in the "Condition" statement that allows this.  Something like: If currentView = AdminView then apply these actions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create as many as required submit data connections.

Put one button in each view, and setup it to execute rules instead of submitting the form.

In the rule, add a submit action to the proper data connection.

Comment: Hmm, That's what I did in IP2007 but in IP2010 I was hoping to use the "Submit" button in the ribbon (it's a Browser based form).  From what your saying, I'll have to create buttons on the Form and set the Form Options to NOT display the "Submit" button.  Is that correct?

Comment: Unless I missed something, the only way to interact when the view change is by code. You can maybe inject javascript in the view's xsl file, but I don't know it works and if it's supported.

Comment: well could also create a web service method that adds the xml to a form library and call this method as default submit action. this method coulld then have a parameter in which library to submit - and in your form you could have a field that changes according to the view